Отправка аргумента при нажатии н кнопку telebot
Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку вызывалась функция (уже), но и передавался аргумент i так как кнопок ответ может быть много
def list_is_set(message):
    global task
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str("Все запросы").format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)

    for i in range(len(task)):
        keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        button_save = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Ответить", callback_data="my_answer")
        keyboard.add(button_save)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(task[i]["text"]).format(message.from_user), reply_markup=keyboard)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'my_answer')
def my_answer(call):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, str(call))


Непонятно, что за переменная task, сделайте код воспроизводимым для других.

callback_data="my_answer #Ваш_аргумент";
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data.startswith("my_answer"));
def my_answer(call):
Ваш_аргумент = call.data.split(" ")[1];
